# Adding A Method to the Global Name Space

Tags: groovy

I've written a method that I can use `ClassName.methodName(args)`.

How can I make it so I can use `methodName(args)`.

I tried monkey patching Object like so:

```
class Object {
    def methodName(args) {
        // method definition
    }
}
```

Update:

I tried what dmahapatro said.

```
import static groovy.json.JsonOutput.*

Object.metaClass.outputJson = {
    return println(prettyPrint(toJson(it)))
}

outputJson([:])
```

Return:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Object.outputJson() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[:]]
Possible solutions: outputJson(), outputJson(java.lang.Object)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Object.outputJson() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[:]]
Possible solutions: outputJson(), outputJson(java.lang.Object)
    at Object.run(Object.groovy:7)
[Finished in 2.1s]
```

The issue created by the edit was because Object.groovy conflicted with Groovy's Object.java. Once I renamed it to ObjectMeta (or any other non conflicting name, it worked).

Comment: `return println(prettyPrint(toJson(it)))` won't work. Only return the `prettyPrint` JSON. `return prettyPrint(toJson(it))`

Comment: You also need to have your closure take an argument:  Object.metaclass.outputJson = { args -> return prettyPrint(toJson(args)) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ExpandoMetaClass` on `Object`

```
Object.metaClass.printsHello = {
    return it
}

assert "Hello" == printsHello("Hello")
assert "Hello" == 'ABC'.printsHello("Hello")
assert "Hello" == 123.printsHello("Hello")
assert "Hello" == new Object().printsHello("Hello")

class A{
    Integer a
}

assert "Hello" == new A(a: 10).printsHello("Hello")
```

This can also be achieved by using `@Category` as below

```
@Category(Object) class CustomizedObject{
    def printsHello(String str){
        return str
    }
}

String.mixin CustomizedObject
assert 'Hello' == 'ABC'.printsHello('Hello')

Integer.mixin CustomizedObject
assert 'Hello' == 123.printsHello('Hello')

BigInteger.mixin CustomizedObject
assert 'Hello' == 123G.printsHello('Hello')

@Mixin(CustomizedObject) //Compile Time Mixin
class A{
}

assert 'Hello' == new A().printsHello('Hello')
```

If you want to distribute the `@Category` in a jar, then include `CustomizedObject` in that jar and use it wherever needed.

```
import static groovy.json.JsonOutput.*

Object.metaClass.outputJson = {
    return prettyPrint(toJson(it))
}

println outputJson([a: 1, b: 2, c: 3])

//Prints:
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
}
```

**Note:-**
One thing to catch here is, we are using `metaClass` on `Object` directly which can be pivotal sometimes, you should clear the `metaClass` from object once you are done with it.

Comment: Are you doing this in the same script? The solution looks great but I tried testing this by setting the method in the `Object.metaClass` but it complains that it only accepts `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: Yes, I have it as a single groovy script run in groovy console. You can also use @Category (as mentioned by @Andrew). You can also go one step above by creating your @Category and @Mixin it whereever required, which would work effortlessly since everything is Java extends `Object`.

Comment: @SunnyJuneja have a look at my update on how to use `@Category` and distribute your functionality in a jar.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far dmahapatro but the category requires that I bind it to a class. Like you do `new A().printsHello('Hello')` but that defeats the point of me wanting to do just `printsHello('Hello')`. Is there anyway to make the first version work? Did you see my update on my question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31888/discussion-between-sunny-juneja-and-dmahapatro)

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities that you can do.  The simplest one is to use categories.  In your main method or script do something like this:

```
use(ObjectExtender) {
  startProgram();
}
```

And then create the ObjectExtender class like this:

```
class ObjectExtender {
  static def methodName(Object self, Map args) {
    ...
  }
}
```

As long as you are inside the control flow of the `use` call, you will be able to call `methodName` on any object.  There are other possibilities, like creating a new metaClass for object, but I'd probably go with categories.

Comment: Ideally, I would like to distribute a jar so that this happens automatically. I imagine if I use the ObjectExtender, I would have to ask everyone to do so. Are my assumptions true?

Comment: Should't the method in category be `static`?

Comment: @dmahapatro Yes, it should. Thanks for pointing that out. Changed answer